# Rails - Service undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a service called `HiringProcedureService` which looks like this

```
class HiringProcedureService
  def initialize
  end

  def log_procedure(procedure)
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

You will notice that this actualy does not do anything yet, but I am just trying to access the method `log_procedure` via controller as following

```
HiringProcedureService.log_procedure(@procedure)
```

But this throws an error

> NoMethodError - undefined method `log_procedure' for
>   HiringProcedureService:Class:

What am i doing wrong and why does it say undefined method, the method is clearly defined.

Comment: `log_procedure` is not a class method, its an instance method for the object of class `HiringProcedureService`. If you want that for the class use `self.log_procedure`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> NoMethodError - undefined method `log_procedure' for
>   HiringProcedureService:Class:

You have defined `log_procedure` as an **instance method**. You need to define it as a **class method** if you want to access it using the `class`

```
def self.log_procedure(procedure)
  binding.pry
end
```

Comment: Thank you, this does help. Can you please help me understand what is instance method

Comment: @Saadia Check this http://culttt.com/2015/06/10/understanding-class-methods-verses-instance-methods-in-ruby/

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

`HiringProcedureService.new().log_procedure(@procedure)`

Comment: With the `new()` call, it enables all methods and variables defined inside the Service